# Which address to state as my own at top of publication?

Tags: publications

i am a MSc Computer Science student writing on a Work-in-Progress publication for ACM SIGCHI.

This format including PDF drafts is defined here:
(http://chi2015.acm.org/authors/works-in-progress/)!

At the beginning of the paper the address for each author is defined separately. Both my mentor (PhD student) and his Professor have their institute address standing under their names, both the same address (institute at our Uni for electrical engineering). Me and my fellow student are studying at the institute for computer science, i.e. another faculty with significant another address and we are not working nor having an office/address there.

What address should be stated under our names?

I think we need an address, under which letters arrive us, which I think is not the case for the electrical engineering faculty nor the computer science faculty of our Uni. Do you think so, too?

Consequently, I think our personal home addresses have to be stated. But then it appears strange or unprofessional, because it looks like we are not affiliated with anyone.

What would you think?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many templates include a place for authors to put street addresses, but they aren't necessarily strictly required.

In your case, if you look at [last year's CHI proceedings](http://chi2014.acm.org/proceedings) you can see that plenty of papers omit it.

For your submission, communication related to your submission will be via email, not snail mail. You can either omit the address entirely, or put the address of your computer science department, it doesn't really matter much. (In the general case, I think it's likely that if a publisher *does* want to communicate by snail mail, they will ask for the preferred mailing address in the paper submission process, not read it off the submission.)

Comment: Yes, examples on http://chi2014.acm.org/extended-abstracts show that people mostly didn't publish their institute addresses, only the institute names including the city name. I think I'll do so, too.

Comment: There are publishers (such as the American Mathematical Society) that send still proofs by snail mail.

Comment: @Shane would that be to the address you put in the text of the submission? Or do they ask for an address on the paper submission site?

Comment: @ff524 I can't remember whether you are asked for an address more than once (I would have used the same address anyway).

Comment: @ff524: I don't know about the AMS, but other publishers ask where to send the offprints in the paper submission site, at the very end of the submission process.

Comment: Computer science conferences like SIGCHI send neither proofs nor offprints to authors, either electronically or on paper.  Authors are expected to supply the paper in camera-ready form (except for page numbers), so there is no need for either.  Addresses are used solely to indicate professional affiliation and to help readers contact the authors later, neither of which require an address because everyone has a web page and uses Google.

Answer (score 4):

Having a publication is, I think, a good enough reason for requesting a mail box from your institution, so you have a possible solution there. If that was not possible, you can always put the professors' addres as a c/o, so the letters are sent to him, and he will forward them to you.

Note that nowadays, the main use of physical addresses in papers are to send you snail mail spam, like professional societies affiliation offers and such. Almost all communications related to the paper would be via email.

Comment: Thanks! Getting an own mail box from my institute is an interesting idea. I think I'll request one for further publications, which I want to do later on this year.

Comment: @GerhardHagerer it shouldn't take long to get, and in any case, the address would be something like _Gerhard Haeger, Computer Science Department, Ada Lovelace Laboratory, University_, so you could just put it in your paper.

Comment: It would not need to be as formal as a mail box, even. Just that whoever is in charge of handling the department's mail knows to hold mail for you until you pick it up. This is something that the secretarial staff can usually handle, because they also handle it for faculty who have recently left the institution.

Comment: @OswaldVeblen in the institutions I have been in, mail is left in a box with the label of the person until they pick it up. Of course, YMMV, but that is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Just give your department as your address. In the twelve years since my first publication appeared, I have never received a single piece of snail-mail related to a publication so, to be honest, the address is largely a vestige of the days before emails. It's much more important to make sure that your email address can easily be found: *that* is how anyone who wants to contact you will try to do so.

Comment: +1 for suggesting department address rather than leaving it empty. If, years from now, somebody wants to ask the author something about the paper, having one more piece of information which can be used to track down the author is nice.

Answer (score 1):

In most departments mail for an undergrad/masters student will go to an appropriate admin office, and they'll send you an email - unless you're well known to the front desk staff who would keep it for you - so you can put your own department's address and not worry about it.  It would seem like a good idea to do so as your publication history will match your CV better.

*Some* journals will require this field - or if you don't give it, assume the lead author's address is applicable - again it woul dmake sense ot give the right address.

Answer (score 1):

The authors' addresses on a publication serve not only (nor even primarily) to help people to contact the authors.  They indicate where the work was done, so that the universities or companies involved get appropriate credit.  Some journals (most of the journals that I'm familiar with) allow an additional field called "current address", where an author who has moved since the work was done can indicate where (s)he can be reached.